# Get a value from bot prompt while using waterfall method C# Bot frameowork V4

Tags: c#, botframework

I am using Bot Framework v4 and within a waterfall method i want a file type value from a prompt.
File types are pdf,xml,docx,xml etc . If user selects xml whole waterfall method starts again ,but i want to store the value from prompt.

Below is the code:

// Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
// Licensed under the MIT License.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Choices;
using Microsoft.Bot.Schema;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Recognizers.Text.DataTypes.TimexExpression;
using AdaptiveCards;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using CoreBot.Dialogs;
using CoreBot;

namespace Microsoft.BotBuilderSamples.Dialogs
{
    public class MainDialog : ComponentDialog
    {
        private readonly IntentsRecognizer _luisRecognizer;
        protected readonly ILogger Logger;
        private Activity promptMessage;

        public string CompaniesSelected { get; private set; }
        public object AdaptiveCard { get; private set; }
        public string CHOICEPROMPT { get; private set; }

        // Dependency injection uses this constructor to instantiate MainDialog
        public MainDialog(IntentsRecognizer luisRecognizer, ActiveDirDialog activedirDialog,BookingDialog bookingDialog, SharepointDialog sharepointDialog,ILogger<MainDialog> logger)
            : base(nameof(MainDialog))
        {
            _luisRecognizer = luisRecognizer;
            Logger = logger;

            AddDialog(new TextPrompt(nameof(TextPrompt)));
            AddDialog(bookingDialog);
            AddDialog(activedirDialog);
            AddDialog(sharepointDialog);
            AddDialog(new WaterfallDialog(nameof(WaterfallDialog), new WaterfallStep[]
            {
                IntroStepAsync,
                ActStepAsync,
                FinalStepAsync,
            }));

            // The initial child Dialog to run.
            InitialDialogId = nameof(WaterfallDialog);
        }

        private async Task<DialogTurnResult> IntroStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            if (!_luisRecognizer.IsConfigured)
            {
                await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(
                    MessageFactory.Text("NOTE: LUIS is not configured. To enable all capabilities, add 'LuisAppId', 'LuisAPIKey' and 'LuisAPIHostName' to the appsettings.json file.", inputHint: InputHints.IgnoringInput), cancellationToken);

                return await stepContext.NextAsync(null, cancellationToken);
            }

            // Use the text provided in FinalStepAsync or the default if it is the first time.
            var messageText = stepContext.Options?.ToString() ?? "Please wait while we are processing your request?\nOr Type Something";
            var promptMessage = MessageFactory.Text(messageText, messageText, InputHints.ExpectingInput);
            return await stepContext.PromptAsync(nameof(TextPrompt), new PromptOptions { Prompt = promptMessage }, cancellationToken);
        }


        private async Task<DialogTurnResult> PromptWithAdaptiveCardAsync(
     WaterfallStepContext stepContext,
     CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            // Define choices
            var choices = new[] { "One", "Two", "Three" };

            // Create card
            var card = new AdaptiveCard(new AdaptiveSchemaVersion(1, 0))
            {
                // Use LINQ to turn the choices into submit actions
                Actions = choices.Select(choice => new AdaptiveSubmitAction
                {
                    Title = choice,
                    Data = choice,  // This will be a string
                }).ToList<AdaptiveAction>(),
            };

            // Prompt
            return await stepContext.PromptAsync(
                CHOICEPROMPT,
                new PromptOptions
                {
                    Prompt = (Activity)MessageFactory.Attachment(new Attachment
                    {
                        ContentType = AdaptiveCard.ToString(),
                // Convert the AdaptiveCard to a JObject
                Content = JObject.FromObject(card),
                    }),
                    Choices = ChoiceFactory.ToChoices(choices),
            // Don't render the choices outside the card
            Style = ListStyle.None,
                },
                cancellationToken);
        }

        //static async Task DisplayOptionsAsync(WaterfallStepContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        //{
        //    // Create a HeroCard with options for the user to interact with the bot.
        //    var card = new HeroCard
        //    {
        //        Text = "You can upload an image or select one of the following choices",
        //        Buttons = new List<CardAction>
        //{
        //    // Note that some channels require different values to be used in order to get buttons to display text.
        //    // In this code the emulator is accounted for with the 'title' parameter, but in other channels you may
        //    // need to provide a value for other parameters like 'text' or 'displayText'.
        //    new CardAction(ActionTypes.ImBack, title: "1. Inline Attachment", value: "1"),
        //    new CardAction(ActionTypes.ImBack, title: "2. Internet Attachment", value: "2"),
        //    new CardAction(ActionTypes.ImBack, title: "3. Uploaded Attachment", value: "3"),
        //},
        //    };

        //    var reply = MessageFactory.Attachment(card.ToAttachment());
        //   // await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(reply, cancellationToken);
        //}

        private static async Task SendIntroCardAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var card = new HeroCard();
            card.Title = "Welcome to Bot Framework!";
            card.Text = @"Select one of the below menu to proceed";
            card.Images = new List<CardImage>() { new CardImage("https://aka.ms/bf-welcome-card-image") };
            card.Buttons = new List<CardAction>()
            {
                new CardAction(ActionTypes.ImBack, "Active Directory Search", null, "Active Directory Search", "Active Directory Search", "ActiveDirectory Help"),
                new CardAction(ActionTypes.ImBack, "ServiceNow", null, "ServiceNow", "ServiceNow", "ServiceNow"),
                new CardAction(ActionTypes.ImBack, "Management Tools", null, "Management Tools", "Management Tools", "Management Tools"),
                new CardAction(ActionTypes.ImBack, "Search Analytics", null, "Search Analytics", "Search Analytics", "Search Analytics"),
                new CardAction(ActionTypes.ImBack, "Sharepoint Search", null, "Sharepoint Search", "Sharepoint Search", "Sharepoint Search"),
                new CardAction(ActionTypes.ImBack, "Comment/Feedback", null, "Comment/Feedback", "Comment/Feedback", "Feedback"),

            };

            var response = MessageFactory.Attachment(card.ToAttachment());
            await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(response, cancellationToken);
        }


        private static async Task SendFileTypeCardAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var card = new HeroCard();
            card.Title = "Welcome to Bot Framework!";
            card.Text = @"Select the doc type";
            card.Images = new List<CardImage>() { new CardImage("https://aka.ms/bf-welcome-card-image") };
            card.Buttons = new List<CardAction>()
            {
                new CardAction(ActionTypes.ImBack, "All", null, "All", "All","All"),
                new CardAction(ActionTypes.ImBack, "docx", null, "docx", "docx", "docx"),
                new CardAction(ActionTypes.ImBack, "pdf", null, "pdf", "pdf", "pdf"),
                new CardAction(ActionTypes.ImBack, "doc", null, "xml", "xml", "xml"),
                new CardAction(ActionTypes.ImBack, "xls", null, "xls", "xls", "xls"),
                new CardAction(ActionTypes.ImBack, ".aspx", null, ".aspx", ".aspx", "aspx"),
                new CardAction(ActionTypes.ImBack, ".html", null, ".html", ".html", "html"),

            };

            var response = MessageFactory.Attachment(card.ToAttachment());
            await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(response, cancellationToken);
        }

        private static async Task SendResCardAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken, List<string> resSpList)

        {
            var card = new HeroCard();
            card.Title = "Sharepoint Result";
            card.Text = @"Click on below result";
            card.Images = new List<CardImage>() { new CardImage("https://aka.ms/bf-welcome-card-image") };

            foreach (var rs in resSpList)
            {

                string[] subLink = rs.Split('/');
                string docTitle = subLink[subLink.Length - 1];
                card.Buttons = new List<CardAction>()
            {
                new CardAction(ActionTypes.OpenUrl, docTitle, null, docTitle, "All",rs),


            };
            }
            var response = MessageFactory.Attachment(card.ToAttachment());
            await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(response, cancellationToken);
        }


        private async Task<DialogTurnResult> ActStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            if (!_luisRecognizer.IsConfigured)
            {
                // LUIS is not configured, we just run the BookingDialog path with an empty BookingDetailsInstance.
                return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(BookingDialog), new BookingDetails(), cancellationToken);
            }

            // Call LUIS and gather any potential booking details. (Note the TurnContext has the response to the prompt.)
            var luisResult = await _luisRecognizer.RecognizeAsync<IntentOperations>(stepContext.Context, cancellationToken);
            Console.WriteLine(luisResult.Intents);
            //await stepContext.ReplaceDialogAsync(nameof(HRDialog), "Hello HR Tools", cancellationToken);
            //return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(HRDialog), new HRDetails(), cancellationToken);
            //var list = stepContext.Values[CompaniesSelected] as List<string>;

           // await stepContext.ReplaceDialogAsync(nameof(HRDialog), list, cancellationToken);
            switch (luisResult.TopIntent().intent)
            {


                case IntentOperations.Intent.ActiveDirectory_Help:
                    await ShowWarningForActiveDirectory(stepContext.Context, luisResult, cancellationToken);

                    var activedirDetails = new ActiveDirDetails()
                    {
                        // Get destination and origin from the composite entities arrays.
                        personName = luisResult.ADEntities.personName,
                        email = luisResult.ADEntities.email,
                    };

                    // Run the BookingDialog giving it whatever details we have from the LUIS call, it will fill out the remainder.
                    //HR Tool should be called here 
                    return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(ActiveDirDialog), activedirDetails, cancellationToken);

                case IntentOperations.Intent.HRTool:

                    //await ShowWarningForUnsupportedCities(stepContext.Context, luisResult, cancellationToken);

                    // Initialize BookingDetails with any entities we may have found in the response.
                    var bookingDetails = new BookingDetails()
                    {
                        // Get destination and origin from the composite entities arrays.
                        Destination = luisResult.ToEntities.Airport,
                        Origin = luisResult.FromEntities.Airport,
                        TravelDate = luisResult.TravelDate,
                    };

                    // Run the BookingDialog giving it whatever details we have from the LUIS call, it will fill out the remainder.
                    //HR Tool should be called here 
                    return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(BookingDialog), bookingDetails, cancellationToken);

                case IntentOperations.Intent.Sharepoint:

                     var fileType=SendFileTypeCardAsync(context,cancellationToken);
                    var sharepointDetails = new SharepointDetails()
                    {
                        // Get destination and origin from the composite entities arrays.
                        SharepointSearch = luisResult.SPDocEntities.SharepointSearch,
                        DocType = luisResult.SPDocEntities.DocType,
                    };

                    // Run the BookingDialog giving it whatever details we have from the LUIS call, it will fill out the remainder.
                    //HR Tool should be called here 
                    return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(SharepointDialog), sharepointDetails, cancellationToken);

                //List<string> res = new List<string>();
                //List<string> list = new List<string>();
                //string searchstr =null;


                //var luisResultSp = await _luisRecognizer.RecognizeAsync<IntentOperations>(stepContext.Context, cancellationToken);
                //SharepointSearchDialog sharepointservice = new SharepointSearchDialog();
                //searchstr = luisResultSp.SPDocEntities.SharepointSearch.ToString();
                //string docTyp=null;
                //if (luisResultSp.SPDocEntities.DocType == null)
                //{

                //    var val=await stepContext.PromptAsync(nameof(TextPrompt), new PromptOptions { Prompt = MessageFactory.Text("Please enter your name.") }, cancellationToken);
                //    var welcomeCard = SendFileTypeCardAsync(stepContext.Context, cancellationToken);

                //}

                //else
                //{
                //     docTyp = luisResultSp.SPDocEntities.DocType.ToString();
                //}

                ////await sharepointservice.writeFile("Hey From MainDialog");

                //res = await sharepointservice.SharepointSearchEng(searchstr,docTyp);
                //SendResCardAsync(stepContext.Context, cancellationToken,res);


                //break;

                case IntentOperations.Intent.Feedback:
                    // We haven't implemented the GetWeatherDialog so we just display a TODO message.
                    var getFeedbackMessageText = "TODO: Feedback";
                    var getFeedbackMessage = MessageFactory.Text(getFeedbackMessageText, getFeedbackMessageText, InputHints.IgnoringInput);
                    await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(getFeedbackMessage, cancellationToken);
                    break;
                case IntentOperations.Intent.ServiceNow:
                    // We haven't implemented the GetWeatherDialog so we just display a TODO message.
                    var getServiceNowMessageText = "TODO: ServiceNow";
                    var getServiceNowMessage = MessageFactory.Text(getServiceNowMessageText, getServiceNowMessageText, InputHints.IgnoringInput);
                    await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(getServiceNowMessage, cancellationToken);
                    break;
                default:
                    // Catch all for unhandled intents
                    var didntUnderstandMessageText = $"Sorry, I didn't get that. Please try asking in a different way (intent was {luisResult.TopIntent().intent})";
                    var didntUnderstandMessage = MessageFactory.Text(didntUnderstandMessageText, didntUnderstandMessageText, InputHints.IgnoringInput);
                    await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(didntUnderstandMessage, cancellationToken);
                    break;
            }

            return await stepContext.NextAsync(null, cancellationToken);
        }

        // Shows a warning if the requested From or To cities are recognized as entities but they are not in the Airport entity list.
        // In some cases LUIS will recognize the From and To composite entities as a valid cities but the From and To Airport values
        // will be empty if those entity values can't be mapped to a canonical item in the Airport.
        private static async Task ShowWarningForUnsupportedCities(ITurnContext context, IntentOperations luisResult, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {

            int a = 1;
            var unsupportedCities = new List<string>();

            var fromEntities = luisResult.FromEntities;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fromEntities.From) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(fromEntities.Airport))
            {
                   unsupportedCities.Add(fromEntities.From);
            }

            var toEntities = luisResult.ToEntities;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(toEntities.To) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(toEntities.Airport))
            {
                unsupportedCities.Add(toEntities.To);
            }

            if (a==1)
            {
                var messageText = $"Enter the document name to search in Sharepoint: {string.Join(',', unsupportedCities)}";
                var message = MessageFactory.Text(messageText, messageText, InputHints.IgnoringInput);
                await context.SendActivityAsync(message, cancellationToken);
            }
        }

        private static async Task ShowWarningForActiveDirectory(ITurnContext context, IntentOperations luisResult, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {

            int a = 1;
            var unsupportedCities = new List<string>();

            var fromEntities = luisResult.FromEntities;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fromEntities.From) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(fromEntities.Airport))
            {
                unsupportedCities.Add(fromEntities.From);
            }

            var toEntities = luisResult.ToEntities;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(toEntities.To) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(toEntities.Airport))
            {
                unsupportedCities.Add(toEntities.To);
            }

            if (a == 1)
            {
                var messageText = $"Search People using Phone Number ,Email id";
                var message = MessageFactory.Text(messageText, messageText, InputHints.IgnoringInput);
                await context.SendActivityAsync(message, cancellationToken);
            }
        }

        private async Task<DialogTurnResult> FinalStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            // If the child dialog ("BookingDialog") was cancelled, the user failed to confirm or if the intent wasn't BookFlight
            // the Result here will be null.
            if (stepContext.Result is BookingDetails result)
            {
                // Now we have all the booking details call the booking service.

                // If the call to the booking service was successful tell the user.

                var timeProperty = new TimexProperty(result.TravelDate);
                var travelDateMsg = timeProperty.ToNaturalLanguage(DateTime.Now);
                var messageText = $"I have you booked to {result.Destination} from {result.Origin} on {travelDateMsg}";
                var message = MessageFactory.Text(messageText, messageText, InputHints.IgnoringInput);
                await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(message, cancellationToken);
            }

            // Restart the main dialog with a different message the second time around
            var promptMessage = "What else can I do for you?";
            return await stepContext.ReplaceDialogAsync(InitialDialogId, promptMessage, cancellationToken);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you share your entire Dialog? What are the entire body of the method ActStepAsync and the method FinalStepAsync?

Comment: Updated the question with full code

Comment: Hi AllTech, the first thing is that I cannot see where you made the call for the PromptWithAdaptiveCardAsync that is the method that contains the call for the ChoicePrompt. Could you explain a little bit what does this MainDialog does? And the other thing looks like you never give a value for the CHOICEPROMPT property.

Comment: @AllTech - Are you still working on this? (Since there are multiple people in this thread, you will need to @ mention me if you want me to see your reply.)